# Finding the limit of a sequence involving alternating signs.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Determine whether the following sequence converges and if so, find its limit.
$$\bigg(\frac{(-1)^ne^n}{\ln^2(n)}\bigg)^\infty_{n=2}$$

I can't figure out how to proceed with this question. Is it perhaps L'Hopital? But then how would you calculate the derivative of the numerator? I'm thinking it's most likely to be the Squeeze Theorem because of that $(-1)^n$. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: your sequence is unbounded(because $e^n$ increases extremely fast), obviously it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\ln n\leq n^{1/4}\implies \ln^2n\leq n^{1/2}
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. Also $e^n\ge 1+n$. Thus
$$
\left\lvert
\frac{(-1)^ne^n}{\ln^2(n)}
\right\rvert
=\left\lvert
\frac{e^n}{\ln^2(n)}
\right\rvert
\ge\frac{1+n}{n^{1/2}}
$$
Let $n\to\infty$ and remember that a necessary condition for a sequence to converge is  that it be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of the $n$th term is $\dfrac{e^n}{\ln^2 n} \to \infty.$ How could it converge?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cauchy's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), you can see that the series diverges, because:
$$
\sqrt[n]{\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^ne^n}{\ln^2(n)}\right\rvert}
=\frac{e}{\ln^{\frac{2}{n}(n)}}
\to e>1
$$

Comment: I haven't looked at Cauchy's criterion yet in lectures. Thank you though.

Comment: You're welcome @AustereTiger 

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own answer.

For $n \geq e$, we have $e^n \geq n$. Therefore, 
$$\frac{e^n}{\ln^2(n)}\geq\frac{n}{\ln^2(n)}$$

By L'Hopital's Rule ($\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form), we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\ln^2(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{2\ln(n)}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2\ln(n)}$$

Through the second use of L'Hopital's Rule;
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2}=\infty$$

Hence, the sequence $\big(\frac{e^n}{\ln^2(n)}\big)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is unbounded and so $\bigg((-1)^n\frac{e^n}{\ln^2(n)}\bigg)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ diverges.